# How to set asterisk sign in flutter with top-right corner of string?

Tags: flutter, ascii

I have an input field which is mandatory. I need to add (*) asterisk sign to with the label.
For now, it is working fine but it is showing in middle along with string.

Here I have an image attached.

For now, It's showing like this. asterisk sign is in middle on text

[image: demo]

I want to make it like this. Asterisk sign in upper of the text

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Something Like this

```
String s = "Test Coop \*";
```